# Typescript - how do you get specific values on Object.entries() on nested, complicated objects that come from a third party API

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm having a hard time understanding objects and the `Object.entries()` method on complicated objects that come from third parties, specifically, [DataDog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/rum/#search-rum-events).

I want a specific metric and I'm not sure how to get to it. I marked it "data_I_want" with a value of "HERE".

Based on what I understand from this API, that function returns an object. An example of the structure looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    "attributes": {
        "attributes": {
            "view": {
                "data_I_want": "HERE"
            }
        }
    }
  ],
  "links": {
        "next": "stuff"
    },
    "meta": {
        "page": {
            "after": "stuff"
        }
    }
}
```

The code that gets it is this

```
RUMApiInstance
  .searchRUMEvents(RUMApiParams)
  .then((data: v2.RUMEventsResponse) => {

    let ddDataViews = data;

    // where I'm stuck/confused
    Object.entries(ddDataViews).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      console.log('values: ' + `${key}: ${value}`)
    );
    
  })
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

[How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

So there's a really long answer but the first thing I tried was basically this, from the answer:

> You can access it this way
>
> ```
> data.items[1].name
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> data["items"][1]["name"]
> ```
>
> Both ways are equal.

When I try this in my context:

`let ddDataViews = data.attributes[0].attributes.view.data_I_want;`

I get an error from VS Code in typescript:

`Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'RUMEventsResponse'.ts(2339)`

Why?

I do notice in the linked answer, that the object is a variable and mine is not? Do you have to like, declare it as a variable for that method to work?

So I move on to try to use the Object.entries() method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. This is the same
> as iterating with a for...in loop, except that a for...in loop
> enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.

So this seems like it's the right direction.

So my logic is as follows:

1. get the entries of the object
2. if its data, then loop over that object
3. inside that object, loop over that object

So this is what I thought up:

```
Object.entries(ddDataViews).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      if (key == data) {
        console.log('values: ' + `${value}`)
      }
    );
```

However, this code doesn't work I get:

> '{' expected.ts(1005)

I'm beyond confused as to how objects work in typescript with third party APIs, how do I get "data_I_want" with typescript/Object.entries() from an API?

Comment: First things first (the error at the bottom): the short version of an arrow function only works with simple statements or expressions; if you write an if block, you need to wrap it in `{` and `}`

Comment: seesh good catch on that one

Comment: The issue is your trying to access the response object instead of its [`.data`](https://datadoghq.dev/datadog-api-client-typescript/classes/v2.RUMEventsResponse.html#data) property. Use `let ddDataViews = data.data;` and your first try code should work fine.

Comment: So when I go `data.data.attributes[0].attributes.view.data_I_want` I'm still getting undefined error. It's because the nested property is an object, right? Like, an object inside an object?

Comment: I go `typeof data.data` and it says object but isn't `[]` the syntax for an array...? so which is it? Like an array of objects? SO JS says it's an object?

Comment: Based on the example you posted it seems to be `data.data[0].attributes.attributes.view.data_I_want` (which I hope is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example above, you should be able to access data_I_want by using:

`data.data[0].attributes.attributes.view.data_I_want`

You mention in a comment

> I go typeof data.data and it says object but isn't [] the syntax for an array...? so which is it? Like an array of objects? SO JS says it's an object?

It should say object :) Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_typeof.asp

Comment: I get confused and really overwhelmed easily when it comes to this stuff thanks for your response.